# Не работает проверка If

Tags: java, android

```
 private boolean checkPhoneNumber()
{
    EditText checkingPhoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number);
    String phoneNumber = checkingPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
    if (phoneNumber.length()<8 || phoneNumber.length()>20)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
private boolean checkEmail()
{
    EditText checkingEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);
    String email = checkingEmail.getText().toString();
    if (email.matches("@") & email.matches("."))
    {
        Email = true;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Email = false;
        return false;
    }
}
private boolean checkName()
{
    EditText checkingName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
    String Name = checkingName.getText().toString();
    if (Name.length()<3)
    {

        name = false;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        name = true;
        return true;
    }
}

    public void onClick(View v){
    TextView Hint = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Hint);
    if (checkPhoneNumber() == true || checkName() == true || checkEmail() == true)
    {
        Intent giftActivity = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, GiftHomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(giftActivity);
    ....
```

Не работает проверка. При вводе любых значений все равно начинается следующая активность.

Comment: Не могли бы вы изменить вопрос согласно [mcve]

Comment: Во-первых, в вашем `onClick` для запуска активности достаточно выполнения любого условия, а не всех сразу, как вы, наверное, хотите. Во-вторых, `String.matches` проверяет, что *вся* строка соответствует регулярке, т.е. единственный правильный `email` у вас - "@". В-третьих, писать `if ( выражение ) { return true; } else {return false;}` не надо, можно просто `return выражение;`, проверка на равенство `выражение == true` тоже лишняя.

Comment: Этот код встречается на последней странице уже  4 раза. Может вам проще заказать программу на фриланс-бирже?

Answer (score 2):

Ваша валидация email совершенно неправильная. Она намного сложнее, чем проверить, содержит ли имейл коммерческое эт, и точку. Кроме того, `matches` не проверяет, содержится ли подстрока в строке. Вы наверно имели в виду `contains`?
А вот как нужно валидировать email правильно, в Android SDK есть специальный паттерн для этого:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(target)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка тут:

> if (email.matches("@") & email.matches("."))

Вы, наверное, имели в виду вот этот оператор: `&&`

Comment: а в чём разница, если это булевские переменные?

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим коментарием

Comment: @КириллАвдеев но писать так всё равно не надо. Лишние вызовы функции.

Comment: @pavel Спасибо за дельный совет, возьму на заметку

Comment: @pavel, это уже 4 вопрос об одной и той же проблеме. Решил вот хоть что-то ответить)